# Issue with routing ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I run the application with ISS after clicking on a class.
The browser starts up with this url. http://localhost:50282/

When I click on Index in my folder Account In Views and
run the application I get this url: http://localhost:50282/Account/Index

Now on both urls I have a register form that links to an action
in my AccountController. 
When I submit the form in the second case I get this url: 
http://localhost:50282/Account/register and the register method is run in my AccountController Class and works fine.

In the first case I get this url and error:

> Url: http://localhost:50282/register
>   Error: 404
>   Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /register

I want the url to go to the second url http://localhost:50282/Account/register
after clicking register no matter where I clicked before running the application.

Submit form view code:

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }
    <h1>Register Form </h1>

    <form action="register" method="post">
    <label><i class="" aria-hidden="true"></i> Username </label>
    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Enter User Name"     required="" />
    <br>
    <label><i class="" aria-hidden="true"></i> password </label>
    <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Enter Password" required="" id="myInput" />

    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show us the cshtml for the register link that isn't working?

Comment: There is no cshtml for the register link. The register method in the account controller returns a different view

Comment: I just need to see the submit button rendering mate for the form that's not working

Comment: added to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify where your form is being submitted to. So change this...

```
<form action="register" method="post"> 
    <label>
    <i class="" aria-hidden="true"></i> Username </label> 
    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Enter User Name" required="" /> 
    <br> 
    <label>
    <i class="" aria-hidden="true"></i> password </label> 
    <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Enter Password" required="" id="myInput" /> <input type="submit" value="Register"> 
</form>
```

To a html helper for your form...

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account"))
{

 <label><i class="" aria-hidden="true"></i> Username </label> 
 <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Enter User Name" required="" /> 
 <br> 
 <label><i class="" aria-hidden="true"></i> password </label> 
 <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Enter Password" required="" id="myInput" /> 
 <input type="submit" value="Register"> 
 }
```

Also you need to add `antiforgery token` for security (`@html.Antiforgerytoken()`). And decorate `Register` action with `[ValidateAntiforgeryToken]` attribute.

See [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/)